# Why do we use exponential distribution to model duration of constant rate events?

Tags: queueing-theory

I have partially understood why. The two major reasons stated are:

1. Time elapsed cannot be negative
2. The cumulative distribution $P(X \leq x)$ increases monotonically and asymptotically approaches 1.

Point 1 implies that the probability density function $p(x)$ should be 0 for all $x < 0$. Point 2 makes sense that as time increases, it is more likely the event will come to an end. But are there no other distributions that satisfy these criteria?

Is there a way to check the validity of this assumption in some real cases. Say, I have some duration data of a process, how can I check if it is drawn from an exponential distribution?

I hope I am not asking two different questions or something.

Comment: Actually $P[x \leq X]$ is _non-increasing_ in $x$ and satisfies $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} P[x \leq X]=0$ for all random variables $X$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant $P(X \leq x) = 1 - e^{-\lambda x}, x\geq 0$. Isn't that monotonically increasing and approcahing 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponential distribution satisfies the memoryless property, which is sometimes a reasonable modeling assumption. Also, often a situation where rare events are happening at random can be modeled as a Poisson process, and you can show that the waiting times between events in a Poisson process are exponentially distributed.

Comment: Ah, so memoryless property is the most compelling reason why it is used? Is there some way to test it with some duration data that I have assumed to be independant?